# Вывести на экран строки с определенным количеством символов из файла си

Tags: c

есть код который должен выводить строки из файла которые по количеству символов выполняют условие n,но он считывает только первую строку в бесконечный цикл при любом значении n
В чем проблема?

```
int main(void)
{
char mem[N];
FILE * fil;
int temp, k, length = 60;
int n;
printf("Enter to n\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
fil = fopen("length.txt", "rt"); assert(fil);
//printf("test1");
long cur = 0;

while(fgets(mem,N,fil) !=NULL)
{
long next = fseek(fil, 0, cur);
if ((next - cur) == n)
   fputs(mem,fil);
 //printf("test1\n");
 printf("%s",mem);
cur = next;
}
fputc('\n',fil);
    fclose(fil);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, что вы вообще такое делаете...

```
while(fgets(mem,N,fil))
{
    if (strlen(mem) == n) printf("%s",mem);
}
```

По-моему, этого вполне достаточно, нет?